# Efficient weighted 1D Clustering (Grouping)

Tags: clustering, k-means, group-differences

I'm dealing with the simple problem of grouping a set of 1-dimensional data (1 feature) according to its distribution in the 1-D space. I know exactly the number of groups I will like to get.
So for k=3 and a set of examples as:
85
84
55
53
52
21
20

they clusters should be something like (85,84) (55,53,52), (21,20).

The set of examples won't be higher than 20, so I could simply use K-Means with k=3 and find the cluster quickly. The issue is that I have to make this calculation many times within my algorithm. In 10k iterations I would need to perform K-Means 90k teams so it seems excesive. I'm wondering if there is a simpler mathematical method that would give me that clustering in O(1) or so.

Comment: Where do **weights** come in?

Comment: I meant that the clustering must group by similar weights, given by the magnitude of each example. Probably this is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using **Kernel Density Estimation** instead. It allows data to be weighted. It doesn't need the number of clusters to be specified beforehand, and in particular knows how to handle data that just doesn't have multiple clusters.

Compute the KDE, and search for local minima to split your data.

Comment: Would not this process be less efficient than a K-Means if needed to compute it constantly? I also need that the number of groups for each sample is the same, even if there are groups with 0 members (which k-means can give).

Comment: You can easily compute this incrementally. With a low kernel width, it is O(n) total, and O(1) update per new entry. In particular if the update didn't affect the previous minima, they will still be minima... Only enforcing exactly k groups (why would you?) you will need to define how exactly this should happen - and why this is correct for your problem.
k-means is popular because of this. But in reality, it will give you k groups even when there aren't *really* k groups in the data. k-means is a really crude heuristic; that needs careful validation at every run!